# gradle refresh failed:No signature of method

Tags: java, gradle, pact

Error 
No signature of method: org.gradle.util.NameValidator.asValidName() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl) values: [pactVerify_Our_Provider]

```
pact {
serviceProviders {
'Our_Provider' {
  port = 8080

  startProviderTask = startProvider
  terminateProviderTask = stopProvider
  stateChangeUrl = url('http://localhost:8080/pactStateChange')

  if (project.hasProperty('pactBrokerUser') && pactBrokerUser != '<YOUR USER>') {
    hasPactsFromPactBroker("https://test.pact.dius.com.au", authentication: ['Basic', pactBrokerUser, pactBrokerPassword])
  }
}
}
}
```

Does anyone know why has this error 
thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/693

Obviously gradle 4.8 support has been fixed in pact-jcm 3.5.19